# Why can't Ubuntu 10.04's apt-get install php 5.2.10 from a ppa?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apt-get

I'm trying to install PHP 5.2.10 on Ubuntu 10.04 using apt-get. I used *Approach 3* from [this](http://2bits.com/drupal-planet/various-ways-running-php-52-ubuntu-1004-lucid-lynx.html) page but instead of using `add-apt-repository` I made a file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa:txwikinger.php5.2-source.list` that contains the line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/txwikinger/php5.2/ubuntu lucid main
```

But when I run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install php5`, I get this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package php5 has no installation candidate
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install php5.2` work? Or `sudo apt-get install php`?

Comment: @new123456 Both of these commands output:
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package php`

Answer (score 1):

Try sudo apt-get install php5   or better sudo apt-get install php5 and press TAB a few times you will the entire list. Choose what you wnat